# Yii2 Advanced Apache Rewrite

Tags: apache, url-rewriting, yii2

I'm trying to setup Yii2 Advanced Template on my server the front-end works but the back-end has problems all the assets return a 404 Error .

This is my Apache 2 vhost :

```
    DocumentRoot /var/www/.../frontend/web
    <Directory />
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride None
    </Directory>

    <Directory /var/www/.../frontend/web/>
            Options Indexes +FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride All

            RewriteEngine On

            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/backend [NC]
            RewriteRule . backend/index.php 

            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
            RewriteRule . index.php

            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>
```

The "..." are in place to make the path shorter, please ignore them .

Also the backend is a symlink

Any ideas ?

Best regards,
Paul.

Answer (score 0):

OK, maybe this will help others too .

What I've done is I've declared an Alias and another Directory directive also an RewriteBase declaration is needed for this to work.

```
<Directory /var/www/.../www/frontend/web/>
    Options Indexes +FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All

    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . index.php [L]

    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>

Alias /backend /var/www/.../backend/web/
<Directory /var/www/.../backend/web/>
    Options -Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All

    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /backend

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . index.php

    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>
```